# Дублирование последнего элемента при заполнении вектора структур из файла

Tags: c++, структуры, while, вектор, поток-ввода

Я новичёк в программировании и это мой первый вопрос на этом сайте.
И так, есть вектор структур:

```
struct data
{
    int         id;
    std::string surname;
    std::string name;
    std::string patronymic;
    std::string post;
    double      hrPay;
    int         hours;
};
std::vector<data> m_personal;
```

Текстовой файл примерно такого вида:
[image: скрин текстового файла для чтения]

Функция чтения из файла:

```
void loadFromFile()
{
    std::ifstream in;
    std::string filename;
    while (1)
    {
        std::cout << "Please, enter the filename for load: ";
        std::cin >> filename;
        in.open(filename);
        if (!in.is_open())
        {
            std::cout << "File is '" << filename << "' is not found!\n";
            in.close();
        }
        else
        {
            std::string temp;
            std::getline(in, temp);
            if (temp != "Worker data " )
            {
                std::cout << "The file can not be read. " <<
                             "Please select the data file for this programm.\n";
                in.close();
            } else break;
        }
    }

    int         id;
    std::string surname;
    std::string name;
    std::string patronymic;
    std::string post;
    double      hrPay;
    int         hours;
    std::string line;
    int count{0};

    //           Вопрос по этому блоку while

    while (std::getline(in, line))
    {
        if (count>0)
        {
            in >> id >> surname >> name >> patronymic >>
                  post >> hrPay >> hours;
            m_personal.push_back(m_data = {id,   surname, name, patronymic,
                                        post, hrPay,   hours});
        }
        ++count;
    }

    in.close();
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "The load was completed successfully.\n\n";
}
```

и функции вывода в консоль (но дело не в них, как я понял):

```
void printHeader()
{
    std::cout << "Worker data \n";
    std::cout << std::setw(4)  << "ID"    << std::setw(12) << "Surname"    <<
                 std::setw(10) << "Name"  << std::setw(12) << "Patronymic" <<
                 std::setw(14) << "Post"  << std::setw(8)  << "h/pay"      <<
                 std::setw(6)  << "Hours" << std::setw(10) << "Salary" << "\n";
    for (int iii{0}; iii<77; ++iii) std::cout << "-";
    std::cout << "\n";
}

void printLine(const data& elem)
{
    std::cout << std::fixed    << std::setprecision(2);
    std::cout << std::setw(4)  << elem.id    << std::setw(12) << elem.surname    <<
                 std::setw(10) << elem.name  << std::setw(12) << elem.patronymic <<
                 std::setw(14) << elem.post  << std::setw(8)  << elem.hrPay      <<
                 std::setw(6)  << elem.hours <<
                 std::setw(11) << elem.hrPay*elem.hours << "\n";
}

void showAll()
{
    std::cout << "\n";
    printHeader();
    for (const auto& w : m_personal)
        printLine(w);
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Вопрос, в основном,относится к блоку  while (std::getline(in, line)) { ... } функции чтения: почему сколько бы не было в файле строк - последняя добавляется в массив два раза?
Вот такой вот результат в консоли после чтения: [image: консоль]

Не могу понять, почему цикл сразу не прерывается по окончании файла.

P.S.: Прошу прощения за обилие ненужного кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема этого цикла

```
while (std::getline(in, line))
{
    if (count>0)
    {
        in >> id >> surname >> name >> patronymic >>
              post >> hrPay >> hours;
        m_personal.push_back(m_data = {id,   surname, name, patronymic,
                                    post, hrPay,   hours});
    }
    ++count;
}
```

заключается в том, что после предложения

```
        in >> id >> surname >> name >> patronymic >>
              post >> hrPay >> hours;
```

которое, допустим, читает значения из последней записи в файле, символ конца строки не считывается, а поэтому последующее предложение

```
while (std::getline(in, line))
```

считывает успешно пустую строку до конца символа новой строки (включая этот символ) в последней записи файла. А далее предложение

```
        in >> id >> surname >> name >> patronymic >>
              post >> hrPay >> hours;
```

уже генерирует ошибку чтения потока, так как нет данных, и все переменные такие, как id, surname и т.д. сохраняют предыдущие значения, прочитанные ранее.

Вам следует заменить это предложение

```
        in >> id >> surname >> name >> patronymic >>
              post >> hrPay >> hours;
```

на чтение очередной строки с помощью `std::getline` опять-таки в некоторую строковую переменную, а затем использовать поток `std::istringstream`. созданный на основе этой строковой переменной, и из него считывать переменные  `id`, `surname` и т.д.

То есть код может выглядеть, примерно,следующим образом

```
if (count > 0 && std::getline( in, line ) && not line.empty() )
{
    std::istringstream is( line );

    is >> id >> surname >> name >> patronymic >>
          post >> hrPay >> hours;
    m_personal.push_back(m_data = {id,   surname, name, patronymic,
                                post, hrPay,   hours});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

И так, благодаря подробнейшим разъяснениям от **Vlad from Moscow** и после нескольких часов экспериментов решил сию проблему переписав этот кусок кода

```
int         id;
std::string surname;
std::string name;
std::string patronymic;
std::string post;
double      hrPay;
int         hours;
std::string line;
int count{0};

//           Вопрос по этому блоку while

while (std::getline(in, line))
{
    if (count>0)
    {
        in >> id >> surname >> name >> patronymic >>
              post >> hrPay >> hours;
        m_personal.push_back(m_data = {id,   surname, name, patronymic,
                                    post, hrPay,   hours});
    }
    ++count;
}
```

следующим образом:

```
std::string line;
int count{0};

while (std::getline(in, line))
{
    int         id;
    std::string surname;
    std::string name;
    std::string patronymic;
    std::string post{"none"};
    double      hrPay;
    int         hours;

    if (count>0)
    {
        in >> id >> surname >> name >> patronymic >>
              post >> hrPay >> hours;
        if (post != "none")
        {
                m_personal.push_back(m_data = {id,   surname, name, patronymic,
                                     post, hrPay,   hours});
        }
    }

    ++count;
}
```